# Using if statement to satisfy two conditions

Tags: c++

I'm coding a simple shoot-a-cannon-ball 'game' for my class and I have to have the program print "HIT" when it hits the target. The code I am using is (`h` being the y axis and `d` being the x axis):

```
if (h > 100 && 680<d<780)
{
    write_string("HIT");
}
```

However it will print "HIT" even if just one of these conditions is satisfied. How do I make it so BOTH of these conditions have to be satisfied before it will perform the operation?

If I need to post more code for context I can.

Comment: You should look up what operator< does but your problem is in this part "680 < d < 780"

Comment: Programming language is not math.

Comment: "`h` being the y axis and `d` being the x axis" then why didn't you named them `x` and `y`?

Comment: Study this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Where did you read that `<` could be used like that?

Comment: "So, I have an x axis and a y axis. I think I'll name them... hmm...`h` and `d` should do it ":)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `<` is a binary operator, and as a result, your expression gets evaluated in ways that you didn't want.

Checking the operator precedence tables, it seems your expression is getting evaluated as `(h > 100 && (680 < d) < 780)`, in which case it is true independent of the value of `d` (because `(680 < d)` = true will result in `1 < 780` and `(680 < d)` = false will result in `0 < 780`). But the value of `h` should affect still.

Anyway, you have to rewrite your if condition as `(h > 100 && 680 < d && d < 780)`.

Comment: `((h > 100 && 680 < d) < 780)`? Are you sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, it was a terrible mistake. Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (h > 100 && 680 < d && d < 780) {
    write_string("HIT");
}
```

You can only do one less than comparison at a time. Do them separately and check are they both true using '&&' operator.

Answer (score 8):

The expression `680<d<780` doesn't do what you think it does.

It first checks if `680<d`, which then gets evaluated to `true` or `false`.

This resulting expression is then compared to see if it is less than `780`, meaning that you could get the condition `true < 780` *or* `false < 780` (Both of which are true, since `true == 1` and `false == 0`).

You probably meant `680<d && d<780`, which checks if `d` is in the range from 680 to 780 through a boolean AND condition.